# Restoring aspnet stored procedures

Tags: asp.net-membership, visual-studio-2013, asp.net-mvc-5, asp.net-roles

I screwed up the stored procs in my SQL database for aspnet authentication/memebership/roles.

I ran aspnet_sqlreg tool on a database without knowing that tool is no longer applicable to the aspnet-mvc-5.  I ran the tool again to uninstall the tables (the new aspnet uses a different naming convention like "dbo.AspNetRoles" instead of "dbo.aspnet_roles" - the presence of new table names is how I knew I had screwed up).

It removed the extra, deprecated tables, but also removed the stored procs (which appear to have overwritten the newer versions, since they are identically named to the previous iteration).  Is there a tool in vs 2013 to reinitialize these stored procs?

I am not a smart man.

Comment: can your dba do a restore?

Comment: No, the dev server isn't backed up (..rage..) but now that you mention it, I can prolly pull it from the last test deployment.  I'd love to know a more "correct" way if there are any, but thanks.

Comment: hate it when that happens...